# MySQL Command Line Modifies Input on Backspace

Tags: mysql, shell, terminal

Not sure if anyone else has experienced this, but searching didn't yield useful results.

This has happened to me when using the MySQL shell client on both Mac and Linux operating systems. When I type a command, pause for a second, then press Backspace a few times, the inputted text changes slightly so that there is an additional copy of the `mysql>` prompt immediately following the actual prompt.

Example:

`mysql> select id, from`

Then I type Backspace and I see something like this (I can't remember whether the copied prompt overlays the original query I was typing or not, and I can't seem to reproduce it):

`mysql> mysql> id, from`

Unfortunately, this problem seems to be random and I can't easily reproduce it, but it happens every so often under the circumstances I described. Not sure if it's a MySQL bug or a general shell bug, but I've never encountered something like that in anything other than MySQL.

Anyone else experience this or know a way to fix it?

Comment: What does `stty` show?  Have you run `set -o vi` on your shell prompt (or through `.bash_profile` or `.profile`)?

Comment: Relaunch mysql after running `stty sane` and see if that helps.

Comment: I'm having this same problem (ubuntu 19, mysql client 8.0.17), and `stty sane` didn't fix it, alas.